# What is the command that has the opposite effect of "zypper addrepo"?

Tags: opensuse, repository, zypper

I've got myself into a bit of trouble trying to upgrade the version of postgres on a server and now I want to revert back as it's caused some issues. I'm trying to back track and to uninstall a couple of repo's. 
I added the repo's with:

```
zypper addrepo -t YUM http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-z-suse/zypper/sles-11sp3-s390x pg

zypper addrepo -t YUM http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-z-suse/zypper/sles-11sp3 pgsrc
```

Is there any way I can run a command to uninstall these? I usually work with Debian and I'm in uncharted territory. I've googled this and someone suggested locating the repo directory and manually deleting them but others disagreed.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but isn't that what `zypper removerepo` is for?

Comment: I think you can try "zypper rr (url | alias) "

Comment: or do it with  YaST

Answer (score 2):

To remove a repository, use `zypper rr` followed by one of `#|URL|alias`

That `zypper rr` is short for `zypper removerepo`

Using your examples:

```
zypper rr http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-z-suse/zypper/sles-11sp3-s390x

zypper rr http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-z-suse/zypper/sles-11sp3
```

Reference:

1. [zypper cheat sheet](https://en.opensuse.org/images/1/17/Zypper-cheat-sheet-1.pdf)
2. [opensuse forum post: remove a repo](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/450112-removing-a-repo)

---